# Icon Font - Distortion (Fix = Font Hinting?)

Tags: fonts, svg, icons, font-face

edit* Based on the first comment, I believe my problem is the lack of font hinting with my approach. Does anyone know how to approach icon fonts created using vector software to solve the font hinting (or lack there of) problem? Help appreciated!

I'm creating a font to use for my icons (just much more flexible and efficient than using images). However, some of my icons get distorted and I'm not sure why. Even very simple icons are doing this. I'm thinking perhaps it's something in my approach. This is what I do:

1. Inkscape - create vector icon that is 960px x 960px
2. Center it on the page and use the Font Editor to create new glyph
3. Create .ttf file using freefontconverter.com
4. Take .ttf file and convert to various other file types (svg, eot, wof, svg, ttf) using www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator. All standard options, except remove kerning and custom subset (just english characters)
5. Use the following code in my css stylesheet (I didn't come up with the code, use a guide I found somewhere, it's somewhere in my bookmarks I think):

> ```
> @font-face {
>   font-family: 'iconFont';
>   src: url('iconfont-webfont.eot');
>   src: url('iconfont-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
>        url('iconfont-webfont.svg#iconFont') format('svg'),
>        url('iconfont-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
>   font-weight: normal;
>   font-style: normal;
> }
>
> .iconFont {
>   display:inline-block;
>   font-family:'IconFont';
> }
> ```

At first I thought it was my old, crappy monitor, but just got a new one and it still happens. Sometimes the edges of some icons will be jagged or skewed. Even simple icons get effected. For instance, a calendar icon with square border... the bottom border is twice as thick as the side borders for some reason. And even the ones that aren't noticeably bad are never crisp like image icons. But I don't understand that because text font is crisp... so I must be doing something wrong?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

If anyone can help identify where I'm going wrong, it'd be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a problem due to missing hinting information to me. Can you give an example? It's hard to tell if you can't see it.

Comment: It'll take a bit, I'll see if I can put together an example and edit my original post to show. What do you mean by "hinting information" (I'll go look it up... )?

Comment: http://readableweb.com/font-hinting-explained-by-a-font-design-master/ that definitely seems to be the issue here. It isn't giving me clear edges... I will go read up on font hinting and see how my approach is not solving the issue. Any further help appreciated!

Comment: @jstacks links 403ed. I have fonts that seem skewed do you think hinting could also cause that?